# HSQLDB - Referencing INFORMATION_SCHEMA in foreign key

Tags: java, hsqldb

I tried to create a foreign key on an existing table.
The FK should reference a column on a table contained into INFORMATION:SCHEMA.

However this doesn't seem to be possible.
Is that right?

**UPDATE**
This is what I execute (as the super user):
`ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (A, B, C) REFERENCES CATALOG.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)`

This is the error I get:
`[42501][-5501] user lacks privilege or object not found: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Not very helpful since the user I'm using as all the privileges possible and the object definitely exists.

Comment: What is the error message, if any, you are seeing?

Comment: See [how to use foreign-keys with hsql create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156408/how-to-use-foreign-keys-with-hsql-create-table).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is a VIEW and as such has no PRIMARY KEY constraint. Therefore it is not possible to create a FOREIGN KEY to reference it.